# How to configure data migration from one model to another . Django?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

There is model `Leads`

with fields :

```
name, phone, email, address
```

and I create model Contacts
with the same fields but with processed data from `Leads`
for example, combine all `leads` with the same names and phone numbers into one `contact`, etc.
how to implement it? whether to create a migration or a . how it is better to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either through shell or management command (if the action needs to be done regularly)

Check Django's [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)